# Why is the syntax, in JavaScript, regex.test(string) and not string.test(regex)?

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, the syntax to search for a match of `regex` in `string` is `string.search(regex)`. Similarly with `match`, `replace`, and `split`.

So why is the regex/string order reversed in the case of `test`, as in `regex.test(string)`? Why not `string.test(regex)` as with the other regex functions?

Comment: Because `test` is a method of the `RegExp` object. So you're testing the regex to match a string. Is not a syntax issue is just a built-in method. You could implement your own String.test method if that's what you want. http://jsbin.com/bejikabedi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Well sure, but that's all clear just from the syntax itself, so that doesn't really explain it. Why is `test` a method of the `RegExp` object while `match` etc. are not?

Comment: I guess a simple way to think about it is that, a string cannot `test` a regular expression, but it makes total sense for a regex to `test`  a string.

Comment: That makes some sense. But does it also makes sense for a string to `match`, to `replace`, and to `split` a regex, and not the other way around? Sorry, I'm not really seeing it yet.

The inconsistency bothers me!

Comment: I really don't know but I guess and it makes sense that the methods `match`, `replace`, `search` could not be in the RegExp object because `match` - you're matching a regex in a string, you couldn't match a string into a regex it makes no sense, same with the other 2 methods. `replace` for replacing something in a string and `search` too. So the most obvious thing to me would be that the `test` method is in the `RegExp` object because you're testing a regex not a string.

Comment: But is not a big deal, as I said you could implement your own method and done.

Comment: Different people likely worked on the separate methods, hence the inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

> So why is the regex/string order reversed in the case of test, as in `regex.test(string)`? Why not `string.test(regex)` as with the other regex functions?

Because that is the way the language is designed. SO is not the place for  discussions or speculation about such language design decisions, the background for which is in many cases lost in the mists of time.

If you're so intent on having a `String#test` function, then

```
String.prototype.test = function(re) { return re.test(this); };
```

or

```
String.prototype.test = function(re) { return this.search(re) !== -1; };
```

with all the normal caveats about the dangers of augmenting the prototypes of built-in types.

Comment: Silly me, I thought SO was the place for discussion of such language design decisions.